# Laravel 4: default format error messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, how to set the default message format for *all* error messages *throughout* the app?

I already know how to format a separate error message...

```
echo $messages->first('email', '<p>:message</p>');
```

...and how to format several error messages...

```
foreach ($messages->all('<li>:message</li>') as $message) {
    //
}
```

...but I'd like to know how (and where) to set the default format for all messages throughout the app.

Comment: can you give more details on what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a lot of view files. I don't want to set the format of the error messages in every single view file, but would like to set this at one single place.

Comment: you can use language file for that..read [here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages)

Comment: The language file is for the actual error message, not the formatting of the message, for example `<p>:message</p>` or `<li>:message</li>`.

Comment: you can use setFormat($format = '<li>:message</li>')

Comment: Where to use setFormat, so the format has to be set only once for all the error messages throughout the app?

Comment: for through out the app,see my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but according to [API](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html#_setFormat):

`MessageBag::setFormat('<li>:message</li>');`

Which means you can also set it (maybe in your BaseController):

`$messages->setFormat('<li>:message</li>');`

Comment: But the 'message bag' containing the error messages is not available in the BaseController yet. See [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#working-with-error-messages), first paragraph: "After calling the messages method on a Validator instance, you will receive a MessageBag instance, ..."

Comment: That's for `$messages` - I see what you mean. May need to resort to first suggestion then.

Answer (score -2):

If you want it through out your app then You can change the default format in file `Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.php` line 22 after that run command `php artisan optimize`

```
/**
 * Default format for message output.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $format = '<li>:message</li>';
```

**Note** If you run composer update/install, you have to change it again

And if you don't want to do this then you can use seFormat() to set the error message format, this you have to do in all your views. For example--in your view

```
$errors->setFormat('<li>:message</li>');
```

Comment: I don't like changing `Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.php`, because the changes will be undone after every composer update. This is how I eventually solved it for now: I created `app/config/validation.php` and set the default error message format there. In every view file, I put `$errors->setFormat(Config::get('validation.errorMessageFormat'));`.

Comment: You never ever ever edit the source code of something that gets pulled in. It's bad practice and a carnal sin.

Comment: Or if you really need to, contribute to the project so that everyone can benefit from it.

Comment: I have clearly mention that in my answer **If you run composer update/install, you have to change it again** This is just in case if the user is desperate to do so. There is nothing wrong in the code